# Converting colo schemes to different applications

Tags: bash, zsh, vim, tmux, theme

Do you know about Project Dracula? https://draculatheme.com/ Dracula is a project where a initially zsh color theme is ported to over 100 different applications.
I love this project, i think it's a great idea, but i don't like the theme that much.
Does anybody know of an easy way to convert existing themes over to different applications?
I'd love to have my bash, vim, tmux, etc all in the same theme.

Answer (score 0):

Some apps are difficult to configure with a script. I believe there's no simple way to configure iTerm2 with a script for example. You have to manually go in the menu and activate the options. Maybe you could use AppleScript to automate that but see how it begins to be very specific to the platform you are using. 
It would take a lot of time to create script that handle all the use cases for each OS / app combination.

It's fairly easy to set up the themes by yourself:

- [Vim](https://draculatheme.com/vim)
- [Bash](https://github.com/allamiro/dracula-bash)
- [Tmux](https://draculatheme.com/tmux)

You could still create a script that works for you and use it later if you need to set up your OS from scratch.